# Calling node functions in order

Tags: node.js

This has been handled before in a few threads but still unable to wrap my head around this, maybe because I am entirely new to node and making a transition for java programmers is usually a bit longer.

Have to basically do this:

```
var data [];
fetchData() // populates data array;

//for each data element

fetchAdditionalData(data);

doSomethingWithAdditionalData();
```

I thought this would be executed synchronously but doesn't appear, any idea how I can quickly solve that with node?

thanks

Comment: you may need Promise, await. in case the functions are async.

Comment: Please try to provide a better example or a more explicite description of your problem, because currently it is total unclear from where and how you try to fetch the data.

Comment: You should really try to explain better what you would like to do and how your actions chain together (or why you need to do it sync, as you explain in one comment). There are way to many questions open to give a good answer

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question according to it afterwards. Your current question suggests that you may have a lack of understanding some basic programming concepts in general, because even if your examle would be in Jave, it doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

The code in node.js is executed synchronously unless it requires resources. If resources are required, the node engine will execute something else meanwhile.

If fetch data is using network/files of the filesystem/any resource that needs to be waited for, the code will be asynchronous. In general, consider the code as asynchronous is safer.

The best ways to deal with that are callbacks or promises. Callbacks have already been showed so I'm going to use promises. If you use fetch, you will have a promise as a result usually. For instance, with the SW API:

```js
//this function return a promise
function fetchData() {
  return fetch('https://swapi.co/api/people/3',{mode:'cors'})
  .then(resp => resp.json()) //just want the json from the response
  .then(respJson => {
  console.log("result of fetchData is " + JSON.stringify(respJson))
  return respJson
  })
}

function doSomeStuff(x) { 
  console.log("Doing some stuff with anArray : ")
  console.log(x)}
  
fetchData().then(data => {
  //here we are sure that anArray is equal to the films we fetched 
  // because of the then
  let anArray = data.films
  doSomeStuff(anArray)
  })
  
//if you come from Java the async/await syntax might be more readable. 
//It is just syntaxic sugar for promises

async function fetchDataAsync() {
  let anArray2 = []
  const swResp = await fetch('https://swapi.co/api/people/3',{mode:'cors'})
  const swJSON = await swResp.json()
  console.log("async result is" + JSON.stringify(swJSON))
  anArray2 = swJSON.films
  doSomeStuff(anArray2)
}

fetchDataAsync()
```

Comment: do you really want to keep `anArray` as a global var? Some laymen might assume that it would be filled after the `then` statement

Comment: that's true, I wrote the code part by part... I'm gonna add async as well

Answer (score 0):

> You can use the callback method, this way you can run your function synchronously.

Below is a function fetchData which will return an array as callback

```
function fetchData(callback) {
  var data = [];

  /* 
   * Fetch the array as required, either through a function or API 
   * and push it to the data array 
   * sample function

     function generate() {

      for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        data.push(i + 1);
      }
      callback(data)

     }

  */



}

fetchData(function(data) { 
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    // You can do something else here too

  }
})
```

I hope this resolves your problem

Comment: thanks but the data array isn't fixed either, and needs to be filled up, after which the next function has to be executed, and ist has to be done sync not async

Comment: This won't work, you need to provide a callback to fetchData like this: `fetchData(function(data) { ...})`.

Comment: @kunerd I fixed it

Comment: Promises offer way more flexibility, and you could use async/await with them in the latest versions of node

Comment: @kunerd which line are you talking about?

Comment: This shows how much I'm dependent on my code editor :(

Comment: In my opinion, your biggest flaw is stating that with a callback the code would run synchronously. Then what is the callback for?

Comment: @Rsh The code from [Théophile Pace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47071769/3231537) is far more easier to use I would say, however, your question simply lacks basic information about what it needs to do, so it is not strange that answers do not match your specific usecase

Comment: @icepickle as far as I understood the question, an array has to be generated and has to be passed on to the next function to execute more tasks using that array, in this case I believe callbacks are better

Comment: Sorry, callbacks and `var` is JavaScript before `Promise` made an entry and before `let` and `const` came. It might be best in your opinion, but callbacks are the past and where good before Promises were common ground in JavaScript